# Finding the greatest common divisor

Tags: java, recursion, int, double

Based off the way they solved this problem on paper:

http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Greatest-Common-Divisor-of-Two-Integers

I am attempting to solve for the greatest common divisor in Java using 108 as m and 30 as n. The problem is that when I run the program, the result ends up being 0. I know I can do this method because I wrote the code myself, yet I hit a stumbling block every time I write a method like this:

```
public static double getGcd_nr(int m, int n){
    int dividend = m;
    int divisor = n;
    int quotient = dividend/divisor;
    int remainder = dividend % divisor;
    int gcd = 0;

    for(int i = divisor * quotient + remainder; i > 0; i--){
        dividend = divisor;
        divisor = remainder;
        if (remainder == 0){
            gcd = divisor;
        }
    }
    return gcd;
}
```

May you please help me accomplish what I need to accomplish. I need to write my own code and not copy someone else's.

Comment: Are you meant to be recalculating `quotient` and `remainder`? I assume so, because of the (currently redundant) reassignment of `dividend`. You're not; reassigning `dividend` and `divisor` is not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(m!=n)
{
  if(m >= n-1)
     m = m-n;
  else 
     n = n - m;  
}
return m;
```

A non-recursive solution for finding gcd of two numbers.